# Converting value into a Decimal

Tags: sql, oracle, casting

I have a percent column that saves values as a whole number. I need to calculate the percent of payments from a payment column by multiplying by the percent column. Currently my table looks like the following:

```
+----+---------+---------+
| ID | PAYMENT | PERCENT |   
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 |     500 |      15 |  
|  2 |      75 |       5 |   
|  3 |    1250 |      20 |   
+----+---------+---------+
```

I need the output to look as follows:

```
+----+---------+---------+-------------+
| ID | PAYMENT | PERCENT |  COMMISSION |
+----+---------+---------+-------------+
|  1 |     500 |     .15 |          75 |
|  2 |      75 |     .05 |        3.75 |
|  3 |    1250 |     .20 |         250 |
+----+---------+---------+-------------+
```

I have tried different variations of the below to convert the percent column into a decimal:

```
cast(percent as numeric (5,2))
cast(percent as decimal(5,2)) 
to_char(percent,'9999.99')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide by 100.

```sql
SELECT id,
       payment,
       percent / 100 AS percent,
       payment * percent / 100 AS commission
FROM   table_name;
```

So for your data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, payment, percent ) AS
SELECT 1,  500, 15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,   75,  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1250, 20 FROM DUAL;
```

This would output:

> ```
> ID | PAYMENT | PERCENT | COMMISSION
> -: | ------: | ------: | ---------:
>  1 |     500 |     .15 |         75
>  2 |      75 |     .05 |       3.75
>  3 |    1250 |      .2 |        250
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ef1e7090d01d67c3f899ac31cea8fbf7)*

---

> Is there another way [to divide by 100]?

Any of these would work:

```sql
SELECT id,
       percent / 100 AS opt1,
       percent * 0.01 AS opt2,
       TO_NUMBER( percent || 'e-2' ) AS opt3,
       percent * POWER( 10, -2 ) AS opt4,
       ROUND(POWER(10,LOG(10, percent)-2),2) AS opt5
FROM   table_name;
```

and outputs:

> ```
> ID | OPT1 | OPT2 | OPT3 | OPT4 | OPT5
> -: | ---: | ---: | ---: | ---: | ---:
>  1 |  .15 |  .15 |  .15 |  .15 |  .15
>  2 |  .05 |  .05 |  .05 |  .05 |  .05
>  3 |   .2 |   .2 |   .2 |   .2 |   .2
> ```

But don't; just use the simplest method that you can.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8b314e6a7448a01b5e2beedb19c42ebf)*

Comment: :D Literally just remembered the /100. Apart from this, is there another way?

Comment: @Codash `TO_NUMBER( percent || 'e-2' )` but dont .... just divide by 100.

Comment: @Codash - or [`* power(10, -2)`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=40556d883298df1ea9964c1352080946), but not sure why you wouldn't just divide...